# Best way to set content type nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am building a backend for a webpage and I have a lot of file types (.css,.js, HTML, and so on), and on node js, I am just checking the file requested with if statements and it starts getting pretty messy. Is there any more elegant way of setting content type?

```js
if(filterReq(req.url)) {
  res.writeHead(403, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  res.end("Acces forbidden");
}
else if(req.url.indexOf(".json")!=-1){
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/json'});
  res.end(fs.readFileSync("./public/events.json"));
}
else if(req.url.indexOf(".css")!=-1){
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/css'});          
  res.end(fs.readFileSync("./public" + req.url));
}
```

Comment: Provide more details such as code that has issue, what you have tried etc.

Comment: @souravsatyam now i use this code for : `if(filterReq(req.url)){
 res.writeHead(403, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
 res.end("Acces forbidden");  
  }
  else if(req.url.indexOf(".json")!=-1){
     res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/json'});
  res.end(fs.readFileSync("./public/events.json"));
  }
    else if(req.url.indexOf(".css")!=-1){
     res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/css'});
  res.end(fs.readFileSync("./public" + req.url));
  }
`
But I am afraid that once I want to add more filetypes, the code will get very messy